# Use Javascript to find text within DIV, insert into HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm currently working on a Safari Extension to create a printable form based upon information provided within a website. A custom CSS stylesheet wouldn't be ideal, instead I was hoping that it would be possible to do the following...

If I were to have the following DIV on page called *name.html*

```
<div id="name">John</div>
```

Is there a way of getting the contents of #name and passing it into a text field in another page called *form.html*? Ideally, avoiding server side scripts?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the element's text (as in **ALL** the text, subnodes included):

```
var value = document.getElementById('name').textContent;
```

Then to assigned the text to the input field in another page:

```
document.getElementById('myField').value = value;
```

Of course that doesn't work across pages. If you don't want to use server-side code for this, one simple way of doing it would be to pass the code in a query string, redirect to your form page, and retrieve the variable from the query parameters. Which sounds simpler than it actually is, as you'd need a function to [add a query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript), another one to [read a query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400245/elegant-way-of-retrieving-query-string-parameter), and to be sure that everything is [encoded and decoded properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672747/how-to-encode-a-url-for-passing-it-as-a-get-parameter).

Another - bad - alternative could be to [use cookies via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cookies+javascript).

Another - better but not yet widespread - alternative could to use the [WebStorage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). (see [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=localstorage+javascript) and/or [sessionStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sessionstorage+javascript)). This will require a modern browser supporting these APIs (for instance, Google Chrome, IE9, Firefox 4, etc...)

*The embedded links will provide the missing parts.*